# Have filepicker.io set s3 file as public?

Tags: filepicker.io

How do I have Filepicker set the proper permissions when uploading to Amazon S3 so that the file is "public" in my s3 bucket?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by making your s3 bucket into a static website.

With Amazon, go to the Properties for the bucket. In properties, the Website
tab has a checkbox to enable making your bucket a static website.

If you need all the files to be https, then you can add the following
security policy to your bucket.

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
               "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
               "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "*"
                },
                "Action": "s3:GetObject",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::NAME_OF_BUCKET_HERE/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In my experience just setting the S3 bucket to static website wasn't sufficient. Filepicker still uploaded the file without giving public access. Only after setting up the above security policy did it finally set public access. Also, Liyan, you should update your docs to include the "Principal" key in your example

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/web/#store

```
filepicker.store(input, [options], onSuccess(FPFile){}, onError(FPError){}, onProgress(percent){})
```

> Public Access
>
> **{access: 'public'}**
>
> Indicates that the file should be
>   stored in a way that allows public access going directly to the
>   underlying file store. For instance, if the file is stored on S3, this
>   will allow the S3 url to be used directly. This has no impact on the
>   ability of users to read from the FPUrl. Defaults to 'private'.